# rails passing value to hidden tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

how I can pass the value from input test to hidden field? I need two form?

**my new view:**

```
<%= form_tag 'https://example.com/api/example.asp', 
    authenticity_token: false do %>
<%= text_field_tag(:text) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("text", @text) %>
...
```

**my controller:**

```
def new
  .....
  @text = params[:text]
  .....
end
```

But it doesn't works

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="hidden">
```

Comment: What really You are trying to achieve ? Having same name inputs doesn't sound like a good idea. Try to describe the problem, maybe there is a better solution than trying to get two fields of the same name work.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons  I know that it is a bad idea, but how I can send the value on the fly? I need to collect the value from text input and  send this value to an external site..

Comment: Do I understand You correctly. There is some value You want to send to two URLs - Yours and external one ?

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons why two urls?  on form there is an action ('https://example.com/api/example.asp')  I need to send to this url the  value via hidden input. Value that I collect from user by text input.  Sorry if I am not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code in your view is in the `new` view?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but try putting `@text = params[:text]` in the `create` action - if you're loading the new action, `params[:text]` will be blank on load

Comment: This is the problem: obviously params is blank on load. I need to send the input text value and send this value to [link](https://example.com/api/example.asp) by hidden_field

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but i thought the point of a hidden field is to pass a variable from page to another - but hidden.  so are you passing @text to the `new` page FROM another page?  or do you just want @text available in `new`?  Say a bit more about your requirements and it's easier to answer :)

Comment: Sorry,  hidden text fields are used on external server to retrieve the hidden text field values properly from the submitted form.  So I need to send via hidden text  the value that I collect from user with an input text .

Comment: ...why not just collect that value directly from the user input?  if i'm being daft, i apologize - but this seems unnecessary

Comment: hidden input were required by the api, but I tried your solution and it works :) big thanks and  the mindless was mine. thanks again

Comment: ah, i see :) if it helped, please check my answer so this question is no longer in the 'unanswered' queue.  welcome to SO :)